# Admob on android : missing xml attribute

Tags: android, admob

I am adding admob adview in my android application's activity :

my code is :

in xml file :

```
<Linearlayout 
>
<Button />
<Button />
<com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.sos.emergency"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="publisherid" />
</Linearlayout>
```

in my activity :

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adview.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        adview.setAdListener(this);
```

And now i am getting following error :

Logcat :

```
  02-13 12:03:42.784: E/Ads(271): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenLayout.
02-13 12:03:42.784: E/Ads(271): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include uiMode.
02-13 12:03:42.784: E/Ads(271): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include screenSize.
02-13 12:03:42.784: E/Ads(271): The android:configChanges value of the com.google.ads.AdActivity must include smallestScreenSize.
02-13 12:03:42.784: E/Ads(271): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges.
```

And in my manifest file i have added following :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

please tell me where i need to edit the code to show ads on my application.

Please see the screen shot of adview it is showing

> You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with
>   configChange

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: fist of all why empty Buttons? and second have you looked at how it's done here http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html

Comment: buttons have valid code in original xml file i jus posted them blank here.And i have followed that link its sample project works i implemented everything following that link only but its showing above error

Comment: have you added the uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest file too?

Comment: yes i have added the permission

Comment: Do you have necessary permissions on manifest?

Comment: yes i have permissions added on manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the new version of the AdMob SDK (4.3.1)? If you are, you're activity would probably have some extra items under configChanges as below:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Also, if you do this and you don't have the target set in your `project.properties` file (probably need to set `target=android-13` or higher assuming you have an Android SDK of 3.2 or higher).

Found this info in a blog post [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).

Comment: can you plese tell me how can i refresh ads on adview i have added `ads:refreshInterval="12"` on my adview but it is not refreshing the ads in adview

Comment: Im getting this error    String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|
 screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize')